# Unable to take "The Loop" Survey

Tags: support, the-loop

Yesterday I saw the ["Introducing The Loop"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/?cb=1) blog post and followed the link to the survey. I started to look it over, but bailed when I saw a mandatory question about "race".

Today I saw that the "race" question is no longer mandatory, so I followed the link again to finish the survey. Instead of the list of questions I had seen previously, there was only a single "To continue, please confirm you are at least 18 years of age" question.

I clicked on the affirmative response, and clicked next. I was then taken to a "thank you for completing this survey" screen, instead of the survey questions.

Now if I try to go back and fill out the survey, I am presented with a "you have already taken this survey" message. Is there a way to reset so that I can actually submit my responses?

Comment: I meant to post this on Meta StackOverflow. Can it be migrated, or should I take it down?

Comment: Try again incognito

Comment: @Alex this worked. For some reason I thought the survey was tied to my SO login.

Comment: @Alex perhaps they wanted to ensure that responses were anonymous.

Comment: The appropriate answer to "what race do you identify as?" is "human".

Comment: @MaximusMinimus, but [what if you're a dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you're_a_dog)?

Comment: @Mark Dogs that identity as human are totally a thing. Or at least humans that identity dogs as identifying as human.